# How to denote the uniform distribution on a compact region in Euclidean space?

Tags: probability, notation

In $\mathbb{R}$, a uniform distribution on a compact set $[a,~b]$ can be denoted by $\mathcal{U}(a, b)$. But how about the notation of a uniform distribution on a compact set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem just about the notation?
I don't personally think it would be a problem to just say 
$$
\mathcal{U}(A)
$$
once the set $A$ is properly determined

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! [+1]

Answer (score 1):

If you define a uniform distribution on compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ as a probability measure that is translation invariant on $K$, then what you are looking for is the Haar measure (normalised on $K$), so what you usually use to denote the Haar measure will be your notation.

Here are 2 explicit examples:

On $\mathbb{R}$, the Haar measure taking value 1 on $[0,1]$ coincides with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$. For a general interval $[a,b]$, the uniform distribution is the measure $\mu$ given by:

$$\mu(A) = \lambda( A \cap [a,b] ) / \lambda( [a,b] )$$

On $\mathbb{R}^2$, write $D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ for the unit disk. Denote $\lambda_2$ for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you are looking for the measure $\mu$ given by:

$$\mu(A) = \lambda_2( A \cap D) / \lambda_2(D)$$

or if you would prefer,

$$\mu(A) = \int_{A\cap D} \frac{dxdy}{\pi}$$

or if you prefer the random variable notation, the random variable $(X,Y)$ having joint density

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{\pi} & \text{if $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$